# How to get STATUS_AKE_SUCCESS in OTR

Tags: javascript, encryption, chat, off-the-record-messaging

I'm trying to get some hands-on with OTR in Javascript. For that, I use [Github Javascript OTR by arlolra](https://github.com/arlolra/otr).

I have a working prototype to exchange unencrypted messages, with OTR by default is encryption turned off.
From that, I assume I don't get the key exchange right and hence am not being able to exchange encrypted messages thereafter.

The switch/case function returns `OTR.CONST.STATUS_SEND_QUERY // 0` on the senders side and `OTR.CONST.STATUS_AKE_INIT // 1` on the receivers side.

But the state never changes to `OTR.CONST.STATUS_AKE_SUCCESS`.

How can I correctly switch into the `OTR.CONST.STATUS_AKE_SUCCESS` and send encrypted messages thereafter?

On the senders side: 
Create the init message for OTR encryption

```
otrClient.sendQueryMsg();
```

Send the message over the client to the other side

```
// send query the message over otr
otrClient.on('io', function(msg, meta) {
var message = {
  type: 'chat',
  body: msg,
  extension: {
    save_to_history: 1,
    dialog_id: conversationId
  },
  markable: 1
 };

  // third party sending;
});
```

On the receivers side:

Getting the message by a listener provided by third party.

```
// MessageListener for OTR
  Thirdparty.chat.onMessageListener = function(userId, message) {
  otrClient.receiveMsg(message.body);
  console.log('userId ' + userId);
  console.log('messageobject');
  console.log(message);

  callOTRState();
 };
```

OTR client handling the message

```
// Receiver reading message
otrClient.on('ui', function(msg, encrypted, meta) {

console.log('callback called');
console.log('msg: ' + msg);
console.log('encrypted: ' + encrypted);
console.log('meta: ' + meta);

callOTRState();
});
```

Function for keeping track of the status of the key exchange state:

```
// querying OTR status
function callOTRState() {
  otrClient.on('status', function(state) {
   switch (state) {
     case OTR.CONST.STATUS_SEND_QUERY:
     // status send query
        console.log('OTR.CONST.STATUS_SEND_QUERY // 0');
    break;
  case OTR.CONST.STATUS_AKE_INIT:
    // status OTR.CONST.STATUS_AKE_INIT
    console.log('OTR.CONST.STATUS_AKE_INIT // 1');
    break;
  case OTR.CONST.STATUS_AKE_SUCCESS:
    // sucessfully ake'd with buddy
    console.log('OTR.CONST.STATUS_AKE_SUCCESS // 2');
    // check if buddy.msgstate === OTR.CONST.MSGSTATE_ENCRYPTED
   // Send here a message saying hello
 sendNewMessage();
    break;
  case OTR.CONST.STATUS_END_OTR:
    // if buddy.msgstate === OTR.CONST.MSGSTATE_FINISHED
    // inform the user that his correspondent has closed his end
    // of the private connection and the user should do the same
  console.log('OTR.CONST.STATUS_END_OTR // 3');
  break;
}
});
}
```

Function for sending a message once OTR encryption is turned on.

```
//send new message
  function sendNewMessage() {
 otrClient.sendMsg('Hello?');
otrClient.on('io', function(msg, meta) {
  var message2 = {
    type: 'chat',
    body: msg
  };

  Thirdparty.send(idChattee, message2);
  });
}
});
```